# JSHint fail if specific Javascript function detected

Tags: javascript, jshint

Is it possible to configure JSHint to fail if it detects a certain function in your codebase?

I notice that JSHint fails if it encounters the word `debugger` but I'd also like it to fail for other custom keywords that we would define in our JSHint configuration.

In particular we are looking for JSHint to fail if it encounters the function `setTimeout` in our code.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you required to use jshint or might it be an option to use something like eslint ([ESLint: Working with Rules](http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules)) ?

Comment: The project is relatively mature and uses JSHint at the moment.  I would prefer to find a solution within JSHint if it were possible, migrating to ESLint might take more time.

Comment: The only option I  know is `globals -setTimeout`, but that won't detect if you call it on the context object itself.

Comment: Sorry - what do you mean by the context object itself?  I was hoping to define a global rule for JSHint to fail if it encounters setTimeout() anywhere in the codebase.

Comment: In the browser you can call `setTimeout` using  `this.setTimeout` (if done within a function that is called without context in  _non strict mode_) or `window.setTimeout`.